# javascript window.onload event handler with and without parenthesis

Tags: javascript

By loading the following simple javascript and html, I get the famous

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

during the window.onload event if and only if I include the parenthesis on the event handler assignment as shown. If I change that line to read

> window.onload = verifyAdd;

(no parenthesis) I do not get the error in my chrome/firefox debug panels. Why, exactly? Is there a functional difference?

Javascript:

```
window.onload = verifyAdd();
function verifyAdd()  {
    var first;

    first = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./frobozz.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <input type=text id=txtFirstName name=txtFirstName size=30 onchange=verifyAdd() />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without `()` means you are assigning the function reference to `.onload`. Huge difference. (In JavaScript, functions are objects so you can do that)

Comment: `window.onload = verifyAdd` overrides the window.onload function to be your verifyAdd function. After doing that doing `window.onload()` would call your verifyAdd function.

Comment: Great - thanks! I must have missed that in my book and on w3...

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

```
window.onload = verifyAdd();
```

you are assigning the result of the execution of `verifyAdd()`which is `undefined`.

By doing

```
window.onload = verifyAdd;
```

you are just storing the function `verifyAdd` in order to execute it later.

The error is due to the body of `verifyAdd`:

```
 first = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
```

You don't wait until your document is loaded (because you are executing the function inmediatly) so the variable `document` is null. Then you are dealing with null references, hence the error message.

Comment: Thanks enmarc, that really clears it up.